# YUI3 event delegation not working in FF2

Tags: events, yui3, event-delegation, firefox2

I am using YUI 3.3.0. Event delegation not working in FF2. Any clue ? Thanks in advance.

```
container.delegate("click", function(e) {

  alert("hi");

  //alerts except in FF2

},"td, li");
```

Answer (score 0):

If the container is a `tr`, you need to reference a `tbody` or `td` element instead, because the `tr` is implicitly wrapped by a `tbody`. The `td` is the element that receives the click before the delegation occurs.